# The pretty format %S does not work how expected

Tags: git

I am using the command `git log --pretty=format:"{ref:%S,From:%P}|"` , but it does not work how the expected. 
[Print from the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiB5o.png)

I am expecting to recive the log like ref:'refs/heads/master

Git's version on my machine is  2.25.0.windows.1. I need to get the commit's branch from the log. I can't use the git reflog, because I am using the library "SimpleGit" to get this information, and this library not have support to git reflog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no branch names listed on the command line, `%S` will *always* produce `HEAD` because that is the name by which the commit was reached during graph traversal.

> I need to get the commit's branch from the log.

Commits don't have branches.  It is the other way around.  Consider this graph fragment, with older commits on the left and newer ones on the right and hash IDs replaced with single uppercase letters for convenience:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

It's clear that commits `I-J` are exclusive to `branch1` and commits `K-L` are exclusive to branch 2.  But—warning, this is a trick question—which branch holds commits up through `H`?

While this *is* a trick question, it also seems to be the one you're trying to get Git to answer for you, using `%S`.  You can't, *because* it is a trick question.

Commits `G` and `H` here are not on `branch1` *or* `branch2`.  They're on `branch1` *and* `branch2`, simultaneously.

If we add a new branch name, such as `master`, pointing to `H`:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

then the commits leading up to and including `H` are now on *all three* branches.

Any given commit—as found by its hash ID, which is its true name—can be on *any number* of branches.  That number includes zero!  A commit can be on *no* branch.  Tagged commits can be like this, and commits made by `git stash` normally *are* like this, on on branch at all.

The set of branches that *contain* a given commit can change from one minute to the next, because whoever is controlling the Git repository can add, delete, or update branch names, and can add new commits to the repository.  Adding a *merge commit* tends to add more names that can reach a given commit, though the details depend on how you manipulate the names afterward.

Given any commit hash ID, however, you can find the set of branch names that *do* contain that commit right now using:

```
git branch --contains <hash>
```

Note that this may produce zero, one, or many branch names.